# Mutually Exclusive Variable Definitions in Nested Randomisations - Python

Tags: python, random

I'm attempting to return an output containing several nested random choices of strings from lists using Python's random module with the outputs of variables from choice 1 being exclusive to choice 2. Essentially, I want **x_choice1** to never equal **x_choice2** in the final output and same goes for **y_choice1** and **y_choice2**. Here's some context... (this is all within a main function, btw).

```
        x = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"]

        y = ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"]

        # Makes random assignment to multiple x choice and y choice variables from x and y lists

        x_choice1 = random.choice(x)
        y_choice1 = random.choice(y)

        x_choice2 = random.choice(x)
        y_choice2 = random.choice(y)

        # z1 and z2 vars combine choices from both lists

        z1 = x_choice1 + " " + y_choice1

        z2 = x_choice2 + " " + y_choice2

        # While loops to make each x and y choice vars mutually 
        # exclusive with additional prints to signal when the program 
        # is re-rolling the value of vars

        while x_choice1 == x_choice2:
            print("reassigning x variables")
            x_choice1 = random.choice(x)
            x_choice2 = random.choice(x)

        while y_choice1 == y_choice2:
            print("reassigning y variables")
            y_choice1 = random.choice(y)
            y_choice2 = random.choice(y)

        # Final variables to combine nested random vars

        final1 = ["first: " + z1, "first: " + z1, "first: " + z1]

        final2 = ["second: " + z2, "second: " + z2, "second: " + z2]

        # Final random selection of nested random vars

        final_choice1 = str(random.choice(final1))

        final_choice2 = str(random.choice(final2))

        # Output both final choices

        output = final_choice1 + " " + final_choice2

        print(output)
```

This works exactly how I want it to when I remove the 'nesting' of the variables (assigning **z1** and **z2**, the random selection of **final1** and **final2**, etc.). For example...

```
    x = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"]

    y = ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"]

    x_choice1 = random.choice(x)
    y_choice1 = random.choice(y)

    x_choice2 = random.choice(x)
    y_choice2 = random.choice(y)

    while x_choice1 == x_choice2:
        print("reassigning x variables")
        x_choice1 = random.choice(x)
        x_choice2 = random.choice(x)

    while y_choice1 == y_choice2:
        print("reassigning y variables")
        y_choice1 = random.choice(y)
        y_choice2 = random.choice(y)

    output1 = x_choice1 + " " + y_choice1
    output2 = x_choice2 + " " + y_choice2

    print(output1)
    print(output2)
```

This outputs something like this:

```
reassigning x variables
reassigning x variables
x3 y1
x2 y4
```

Which every time never has the first x equivalent to the second and same for y and also triggers the message if it has to re-roll the choices, so I know it works.

How can I make the while loops in the first example work in the same way? At the moment it does trigger the "reassigning variables" message but then the values always return the same (ex. x4 x4, y2 y2).

Comment: Note that x = ["x1"] will throw you into an infinite loop, and checking the length doesn't save that because x = ["x1","x1"] will do the same thing. A better way to implement this might be to convert the lists into sets and then select x2 from x.remove(x1) which will let you know when there are no permissible choices, without rerolling.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your reassigning loop runs after you assign z1 and z2, so the result never ends up in z1 and z2. When you initially assign z1 and z2, the variables contain a reference to *the current value of x1/x2 and y1/y2*, and when x1/x2/y1/y2 are changed, their values change but not the ones in z1 and z2. The fix here is just to move the while loops to before the z1/z2 reassignment:

```
    x = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"]

    y = ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"]

    # Makes random assignment to multiple x choice and y choice variables from x and y lists

    x_choice1 = random.choice(x)
    y_choice1 = random.choice(y)

    x_choice2 = random.choice(x)
    y_choice2 = random.choice(y)

    # While loops to make each x and y choice vars mutually 
    # exclusive with additional prints to signal when the program 
    # is re-rolling the value of vars

    while x_choice1 == x_choice2:
        print("reassigning x variables")
        x_choice1 = random.choice(x)
        x_choice2 = random.choice(x)

    while y_choice1 == y_choice2:
        print("reassigning y variables")
        y_choice1 = random.choice(y)
        y_choice2 = random.choice(y)

    # z1 and z2 vars combine choices from both lists

    z1 = x_choice1 + " " + y_choice1

    z2 = x_choice2 + " " + y_choice2

    # Final variables to combine nested random vars

    final1 = ["first: " + z1, "first: " + z1, "first: " + z1]

    final2 = ["second: " + z2, "second: " + z2, "second: " + z2]

    # Final random selection of nested random vars

    final_choice1 = str(random.choice(final1))

    final_choice2 = str(random.choice(final2))

    # Output both final choices

    output = final_choice1 + " " + final_choice2

    print(output)
```